# How reference Universal Windows DLL in Console app

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I writing the Universal Windows DLL targets for SDK 10493. I set all for Console app like shown [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/practice-sharing/2015/08/04/how-to-call-the-windows-runtime-component-in-standard-c/). For testing purposes Id like use Console app but can`t reference to my DLL - error "two projects targets different platforms". Is it possible make reference like I need?